# Extract bzip2 file line by line

Tags: linux, command-line, compression

I have a 17GB bzip2 file that contains 126 million json objects. One on each line.
I would like to perform some computation on every json object on it using `jq`.

Unfortunately, processing the bzip2 file takes ages.

1. ) I tried to put the document to /dev/shm so that it is in RAM.
2. ) I have 56 cores to work with and 256GB of ram so I tried `pbzip2 -d` to decompress, however, it seems not to give me any reasonable speedup.

`pbzip2 -m5000 -d --stdout measurement.json.bz2 | pv -l -cN pbzip2 | parallel --pipe --line-buffered 'jq -rc "select(.value.error==null)"' | pv -l -cN results > out.res`

Unfortunately, this only gives me around 20k lines/s at the pbzip2 level, which takes around 2hours for a full sweep through the document.

The thing is since the document contains a lot of independent JSON objects, i think it is not necessary to decompress it top-down.
Is there a way to parallel decompress a bzip2 file on a per-line basis to better utilize parallelization?

Answer (score 1):

`bzip2` and friends are single threaded. This translates into the fact, that files compressed with **regular** `bzip2` won't see a speedup when decompressed with `pbzip2`. This is a much too little appreciated fact in many-core setups.

So basically you are decompressing on a single core, limiting your throughput. There is no way I know of out of this, as long as you don't have the possibility to make the compressing side use a parallel-friendly compressor.

Comment: Thank you. Can you recommend something parallel-friendly?

Comment: Just use `pbzip2` on the compressing end as well - the opposite direction works fine.